# simple way to ship a small database with an html app

Tags: html

I have an html/css/js single page app whose files are :

```
index.html
css files
js files including jquery mobile
cache manifest file
```

I compile the app for android using phonegap build and I also provide it on a server as a pure web app that can work offline (cache manifest)
The app needs to use a small database (a few lines of tab separated text) to work.
And the database needs to be updated sometimes (once a month maybe).

What is the best, up-to-date way, to ship this little database with my app, and to regularly update it by copying the server version ?

Comment: It largely depends upon the format of the data, and what it's going to be used for. That having been said, sounds like this is a job for a JSON or XML file...

Comment: @BenM the format is just a table of text strings, there's just about 15 columns and around 300 lines. The text string are tab separated. What do you recommend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to retrieve the database from a server using an `ajax` request on the first launch of the app, and then to write is in the localStorage to make it available offline.
Every time the app is launched again by the user, if online, I use the `ajax` request to check if the database has been updated. And if so, I overwrite the localStorage.